How to justify our beliefs so that it is not circular?
Solipsism can explain our experience using the smallest number of entities.
The existence of other minds can explain our experience using a much larger number of entities.
How can we reject solipsism?
Since two explanations can explain our experience, there are obvious conditions, so Occam's razor can be applied.
How to justify why we rejected solipsism?
If we refer to philosophers or experts, it will be circular.
If we refer to our own experience, science and observation, it will be circular because we rely on other minds.
What to do?
Thank you

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Solipsism can explain our experience using the smallest number of entities.

This is logically inconsistent. If we are different people each having our own experience, then solipsism is false.
My experience is that I believe in other minds. Solipsism doesn't explain my experience.
Somebody else may say that solipsism explains their experience, but it cannot explains both their experience and mine.
The argument from the number of entities is a red herring. It is a misunderstanding of the principle of Occam's razor. Occam's razor doesn't say that a theory with a small number of postulated entities is correct and doesn't say that it is for that reason better than other theories. Occam's razor is the idea that we shouldn't needlessly multiply the entities. Ultimately, we can accept a  theory only if we believe that the entities it postulates exist. I believe in other minds, so it is not a problem for me if a theory postulates a multiplicity of minds.
Ultimately, it comes down to what you believe, and this applies across the board, to whatever the subject matter may be. No one needs any justification for believing what they already believe. We use explanations to convince other people, not ourselves. I don't see how a solipsist could convince me that he only exists. In fact, I don't see why a solipsist would need convince other minds that they don't exist.
Solipsism is just a concept. No one really believes that they are the only mind which exists. The discussion of solipsism is yet another failed attempt at understanding logic.
We don't need to justify our belief that there are other minds. This is what I also believe, prove me wrong if you can. If someone claimed theirs is the only mind that existed, I would just laugh and mind more important business.

I know how to justify the existence of other minds. I do not know how to reject the small number of entities offered by solipsism. The small number of entities is a reason to believe in solipsism. How can we reject the small number of entities that solipsism has? Thank you

Can I refer to philosophers and scientists to justify why I reject the quantitative simplicity of solipsism?

The small number of entities isn't a reason to believe in solipsism. Why do you keep insisting on this even though people have told you it's pure non sense? There's no principle that just because a theory postulates less entities mean you should accept it.

Also, if quantitative simplicity is all you need or care about, "nothing exists" is a better worlview. The best one, in that case.

@Arnold See my edit. As long as we cannot perceive the minds of other people, it is at least (just) conceivable that other minds don't exist just as it just conceivable that someone would believe that the world around him doesn't exist. You believe what you please.

I think it's also worth pointing out that Occam's razor isn't really something that can be used as the basis for proving anything.  It's more like a rule of thumb.

If anything, I would say Occam's razor is an argument against solipsism, not for. Solipsism requires your mind to have made up an incredibly complex but consistent world that looks like it contains lots of other people, and your mind is accounting for everyone else's behaviour. That's a lot more complex than just having one mind per person. The OP's argument in favour of solipsism relies on the claim that "one incredibly complex mind" is simpler than "several simple minds", and that claims seems hard to defend.

I don't know why you keep stubbornly assert that solipsism is supported by Occam's Razor just because it posits quantitatively less entity, even though people has been telling you that claim is pure nonsense.
See this page: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/simplicity/
"The default reading of Occam’s Razor in the bulk of the philosophical literature is as a principle of qualitative parsimony.". Occam's Razor work on qualitative parsimony (number of types of entity), not quantitative parsimony.
One's mind is already a kind of entity, assuming that other minds exist doesn't increase the number of type of entity, and wouldn't violate principle of Occam's Razor. To see how quantitative parsimony doesn't work, suppose I give you a box and tell you there's 1-1000 beads in that box. The probability that there's only 1 bead in the box is not higher than the probability that there are 1000 beads in the box.
And again, another reason why Occam's Razor can't be used to support solipsism is that it's only applied when other things are equal. That is, when two theories are equally good, but one is committed to less kind of entity than the other, then we should prefer that one.
For example, let's say we have two theories (a) and (b) that are equally good and (a) is committed to 3 kinds of entities: A,B,C and (b) is committed to 2 kinds of entities: A,B. Here C would be considered superfluous ontology, and would be "shave off" by Occam's Razor. So we have a reason to prefer (b) to (a).
However, if we have two theories that are committed to different kinds of entities, Occam's Razor can't be used.
For example, theory 1 is committed to: A, B, C; and theory 2 is committed to: A, D, E, F. Here other things aren't equal, B, C, D, E, F only appear in one theory and can't be shaved off by Occam's Razor.
Solipsism and non-solipsism theory are committed to vastly different type of entities, hence other things aren't equal.
Solipsism is committed to: one's mind and its mental contents.
Non-solipsism is committed to: one's mind, billion of other minds, and billion of other things.
Here other things aren't equal, so Occam's Razor can't be used to support solipsism. (And again, just because non-solipsism is committed to quantitatively more entities does not mean this is a reason to believe in solipsism. Occam's Razor works on TYPES OF ENTITY!)
Edit: Also, referring to philosophers or expert is not circular reasoning. It may not be the most sound reasoning, but it's not circular.

But even here I refer to other minds when I ask questions. That is, I refer to your own opinions anyway, since I myself have no way of knowing which version of Occam's Razor is correct. I reject the quantitative simplicity of solipsism because it is unconvincing, implausible, and because science, philosophy, and everyday life say that a small number of entities is no reason to believe in solipsism. But I don't know if it's wise to rely on science and philosophy because it means I have to rely on other minds.

Why would relying on principles of science and philosophy mean that you have to rely on other minds?
For example, if someone ask you: "Why is Eart not flat" and you answer: "Because scientists said so.". This isn't circular reasoning, because the conclusion isn't in the premise.

But philosophy and science are the opinions of others. I believe that a small number of entities is not a reason to believe in solipsism because scientists and philosophers have said so. Will this be a rational justification?

" I believe that a small number of entities is not a reason to believe in solipsism because scientists and philosophers have said so. Will this be a rational justification?"
This depend on the authoritative source that you are relying on. For example, you see an overwhelming number of scientists that believe Earth is sphere, then you have a good reason to believe that Earth is sphere.
Similarly, you see an overwhelming number of philosophers who do not use quantitative parsimony as justification for solipsism. This is not circular reasoning, and would be considered would be rational.

But relying on the consensus of scientists and philosophers regarding the existence of other minds will necessarily be circular. Am I not understanding something?

No, why would it be circular?

We rely on other minds to infer that other minds exist. There must be independent sources.

No, why would we need to refer to other minds to infer that other minds exist? And referring to philosophical reasoning of others doesn't equal referring to other minds.

I do not consider the small number of entities a reason to believe in solipsism because scientists and philosophers think so - I already rely on what other minds believe.

So what? Why is it circular to rely on opinion of others? It's possible that they are wrong, but it's not circular.

But if you haven't proven that other minds exist, how can you rely on other minds?

I don't rely on other minds, I rely on philosophical reasoning of people smarter than me. Philosophical reasoning of people smarter than isn't other mind.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Will it be circular reasoning to rely on the opinions of philosophers and scientists?

No its not. I have told you this many times and you still don't understand?

@Arnold And yes you can rely on philosophers and scientists' opinion. They overwhelmingly reject solipsism. So that's a good reason not to obsessively worry about solipsism. And I hope you don't ask the same question over and over again.

@Arnold and I repeat again, relying on opinion of philosophers and scientists is not cIrCuLaR reasoning! The conclusion is not in the premise. I hope you don't ask this question over and over again.

@Arnold if you don't care much about this subject, you can just rely on philosophers and scientists' opinion. They overwhelmingly reject solipsism. You can just rely on their opinion and believe that this is a good reason not to believe in solipsism.
I have to repeat this over and over again in case you are too slow to understand. And again, I hope you don't ask the same question over and over again.

@Arnold I have explained why relying on philosophers and scientists' opinion is not circular reasoning in our conversation in the chat yesterday. So if you don't understand anything, I can only recommend rereading our previous conversation. Don't ask me why relying on philosophers and scientists' opinion is not circular reasoning again. I'm tired.


How to justify our beliefs so that it is not circular?

Descartes postulated that the theoretical basis of our concepts rest on "clear and distinct ideas" which he implicitly takes to be shared by any other human being.

Solipsism can explain our experience

Solipsism doesn't explain itself. And you are merely asserting this without justifying your position. Moreover it is a position that no respected philosopher has ever taken. It was considered by Al-Ghazali but he rejected it on the basis of his theology in that Allah ensures we trust our sense, both external and internal. In fact, I would suggest tjat anyone who is actually a solipsist is likely to be considered an extreme example of a psychopathic narcissist.

A Christian philosopher named Alvin Plantinga would say that belief in other minds is what's called a properly basic belief.  The way he describes it, you don't base the belief strictly on external evidence; it's more like you "just know" that it's true.  I would say that your "properly basic" belief in other minds evidences itself in the question, as noted by others; for instance, phrases like "our beliefs"; "our experience"; or the mere act of asking "other minds" on a forum what they think about the question.  :)
As for avoiding circularity, the only way to ultimately do this is to have beliefs "grounded" in something.  Some Christian philosophers would use this overall argument as one evidence for God; i.e., if there isn't something eternal, necessary, and transcendent, all reality is contingent and (ultimately) circular.  A dictionary is a very large circular reference manual (English words are described in other English words, in one large self-referencing map, for instance).  A dictionary has meaning only because the words stand as symbols for reality outside itself.  Similarly, for contingent reality itself to be non-circular, it needs to be grounded in something which itself needs no grounding; a necessary, eternal, transcendent Being, or God.

The leap between "grounded in something" and "a Being, or God" is gigantic.

@RomainValeri To reduce the "leap" some, I guess I'd say the ultimate "grounding" would at least need to be necessary (not contingent), transcendent, eternal, and without need for grounding itself.  Otherwise it wouldn't be eligible for ultimate grounding.

Would solipsism itself be circular? Seems like it's a self-defeating idea.

@ScottRowe Good question, at the very least I'd say the idea can't be meaningfully and consistently communicated, because communication implies the existence of another mind.

The alternative to foundationalist (your "proper basic beliefs") and circular is holistic. You are framing a false dichotomy here.

Thanks for the reference @Philip, I will try to read up on the holistic view when I get a chance.

@Philip, does the holistic approach deal only with epistemology, or also with metaphysics?  Do you recommend any particular source for me to read up on it?

There are holistic approaches for scientific theories, meaning, epistemology, and ontology. The original idea is callled Durham-Quine-Thesis, guess you can work your way from there since there are many sources with different directions from there.

Thanks @Philip, I'll look into that.  I'll be interested to see how they explain avoiding issues of (ultimate) self-reference without transcendent grounding.

A good discussion of that but on pretty high level is this book.

@PeterRankin To conclude Alice murdered Bob, you might consider the combination of Bob's dead body, a bloody knife with Alice's fingerprints, witnesses seeing Alice enter and leave the scene, evidence of Alice's earlier or later actions (alluding to motive), etc. We wouldn't say these individual pieces of evidence are "circular", but still they add up in such a way to make Alice murdering Bob the most reasonable explanation. Similarly, I'd argue that the sum of our sensory experiences add up to making the existence of other minds the most likely explanation, with no transcendent grounding.

Not necessarily large @RomainValeri. God need not be a person. In fact most religions are less personal-god oriented than Christianity. In Hinduism for example being is definitionally God. Not a being but being qua being

@NotThatGuy Thanks for the explanation, that helps.  I'll need to look into the concept some more and give it some thought to be sure I'm fully understanding it before responding.

@Rushi The leap I'm refering to is the (somewhat "smuggled in") addition of properties to the "something". The "God" label carries a lot of completely unwarranted baggage.


How can we reject solipsism?
IMO history shows that there is no
philosophical argumentation which rejects solipsism.
Hence if
solipsism seems a problem or a challenge for someone I recommend to proceed in a
pragmatic way: To watch how a solipsist acts in real life. Does he/she
behave according to his claims of solipsism? Or is the solipsism just
an exercise to improve one’s rhetorical capabilities and to show the
strenght of one’s own superior rationality?

How to justify why we reject solipsism?
Why to strive for a general
refutation of solipsism?  I for myself do not rely on solipsism
because I do not consider solipsism a satisfying explanation, but the
easy way to substitute explanation by a killer argument.



A reasonable argument if we have reasonable argumentors! I don't believe that is the case for this questioner. He makes it to this list Anyways... +1

What about the Private Language Argument?

@CriglCragl Could you please explain in simple words what a private language is? Its syntax, semantics, pragmatics?


How to justify why we rejected solipsism?

We tentatively reject it, like any other belief, until it meets its burden of proof.
Until then, trying to "reject" it is somewhat futile, or at least unnecessary.
The small number of entities might be a reason to consider solipsism, but definitely not enough to be a compelling worldview. Its possibility has to be demonstrated first, then its actuality.
Also, the very first sentence of your question ("Solipsism can explain our experience using the smallest number of entities.") seems unwarranted at best. How does it explain anything? It's an assumption about one experience, which is then supposed to be a totality, the totality. Even as an hypothesis, I'm unsure it's even valid. But how does solipsism explain other people's experiences? It doesn't. It handwaves them away, which is not an explanation, but a cope out, if I may.

The small number of entities is a reason to believe in solipsism. How can we reject this reason? We have to explain why this reason does not make us solipsists.

Can we in this case rely on scientists and philosophers who believe that quantitative simplicity is not more likely?

We don't rely on people, we rely on arguments, models, ideas. "Quantitative simplicity" is not enough. What's the claim?

Why does Occam's razor only work with types of entities and not with the number of entities themselves?

@andrós Sollipsists can't be gullible. No one there to convince them of anything ;-)

I want to learn how to reject the quantitative simplicity of solipsism. You can't explain it. What is this forum for then?

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/simplicity/#QuaPar Quantitative simplicity is defended here.

Are you reading my questions?

@Arnold If he does read your questions, sollipsism is false.

@RomainValeri By the same argument, if he is choosing not to read the questions, solipsism is still false. BTW, I spell "solipsism" with a single 'l': if we disagree over the spelling we are also refuting solipsism.

@SimonCrase Just a typo on my part :-) Apologies.

@RomainValeri How can you apologize if solipsism is true? Unless you apologize to yourself for offending yourself;-)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100000000000000000000000000000000000. Do you know what it is? You don't. So I am a part of whatever reality looks like that is independent of you. Other people could do the same so they are all parts of reality independent of you too. You can adopt solipsism only by slapping a label on everyone else saying they are all somehow parts of you even though they have information you don't. So solipsism is just non-solipsism with extra unexplained labels on it and is refuted by having a bunch of unexplained complications, see "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch Chapter 4.
This is a criticism of solipsism. It doesn't justify rejecting solipsism. Justification is a process that allegedly shows ideas are good or true or something along those lines. Any such process would require making arguments that use statements and rules of inference. There is no way to show those statements and rules are correct or probably correct or anything like that since there is no way of ruling out the possibility of making a mistake and being right or wrong is a binary status. Rather, as pointed out by Karl Popper in "Realism and the Aim of Science" Chapter I, in On the Sources of Knowledge and of Ignorance knowledge is created by guesses controlled by criticism and justification is impossible and unnecessary. See also
https://criticalfallibilism.com/yes-or-no-philosophy/

Frame Challenge
If I understand solipsism, it is the belief that  only one's mind is sure to exist. If you are the only person who exists, then I, and the other StackExchange users, do not exist, so we can't answer your question. Conversely, if you are asking us to comment, you must at least consider the possibility that someone, other than your good self, exists: ergo, you are not a true solipsist.
On reflection, I think solipsism is, in fact, circular: if I am the only person who exists, I'm the only person I need to convince.

Solipsism can explain our experience using the smallest number of entities

Can it? If I am the only person who exists, I must be really complicated. For example, I appear to own a textbook on quantum field theory, but I have to work really hard to understand it. How did I manage to make it up?

1st para — splendid! 2nd — Not so sure... What if I'm a solipsist, and so sure of myself that I don't enter discussions at all? In a sense this is tautologically true for all of us — we take our perception and perspective as the true state of affairs. At least as the default.  In short, the 2nd para weakens the first. Put differently, solipsism is a serious instance of a pathological philosophy. Most repudiations focus on the pathology not on the substance.

How did I make up something as complicated as QM? The same way I fear dragons crocodiles and other "friends" I myself make up when I dream. Beware! Trite repudiations of solipsism are as ineffective as Johnsons kick

@Rushi One plausible scenario is that the proposed solipsist asker is actually God with amnesia, or an AI that fell in to its own simulation and forgot. Then it would make sense for that one to be wondering what is up, and to in fact have been the author of that universe and the only actual mind in it. But unless it created a being as smart as itself in there, good luck! Might take a while to figger it all out. What if that one 'dies' in there? Does it then wake up to the reality, or does the whole thing quit?

@Rushi I am reminded of Robert Heinlein's story  '—All You Zombies—', solipsism plus time travel.
